# Android emulator as window inside Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Is it possible to put the emulator inside eclipse, as a tab/window?  I've got dual monitors and my typical setup is eclipse full screen on one side and chrome full screen on the other one typically on an developer.android.com or stackoverflow and the emulator UNDER chrome most of the time until I'm debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is possible in Eclipse, most probably not (I could be wrong).

You can try out [MotoDevStudio](http://developer.motorola.com/tools/motodevstudio/) though. The development environment looks exactly like Eclipse, so you wouldn't have much trouble switching over. And more importantly, it has the Android Emulator running inside a tab in the IDE.